# How the number of decision variables have effects on the populations in NSGA-II?

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I just have started reading the NSGA-II code in Matlab recently, and I don't understand what the number of decision variables setting relates in the initialization state in genetic algorithm. Is it related to the test function or used for other intention?

I would appreciate it if you would be so kind to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of decision variables is related to the number of genes in the chromosomes of each individual.

Let's say you are trying to optimize a function `f(x,y)`. Then you have two decision variables, and therefore your chromosomes will be `R^d` where d = 2.

Knowing the number of decision variables is essential to the metaheuristics such as genetic algorithm because much of its operators rely on it, e.g., to perform crossover you need to know the size of the chromosome (size of your representation) so you can iterate and create the offspring, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind answer! 
There are some more questions I want to settle:
1. Are these decision variables just a number?  Could it be a vector or other things? 
2. Are the chromosomes the different combinations of these decision variables? 
3. If the number of decision variables are 3, like, f(x,y,z), can we call the problem which is going to be optimized a 3-objective problem?

Comment: @Yetzerhara yes, the decision variables are essentially a vector (the chromosome) (you can see as a d dimensional vector where d is the number of variables, therefore your chromosome is a vector in R^d). Chromosomes are the container in which the essential data of your problem is encapsulated. For the same problem, multiple encoding schemes could exist, and different decoding schemes could exist too. During decoding, you can apply constraints to the variables. Regarding f(x, y, z), you cant call it 3-objective problem because x, y, z are your decision variables.

Comment: You could call it multi-objective optimization if you have multiple objective functions, e.g., say f1(x, y, z), f2(x, y), f3(y, z). Here the problem could be to minimize f1 while maximizing f2 and f3... or minimizing or maximizing f(f1, f2, f3).

Comment: That's quite informative! I think I start to understand the basics of multi-objective optimization. Thanks again for your excellent answer!